# Mail list edit confirm pages and post backs

Tags: ajax

I'm currently using the mail list extension (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/mailinglist/index.html) on one of my sites and I have a few questions which I couldn't find the answer too using google and the documentation.

I wish to edit the Post back page so that it can be branded up with the rest of the website. And I plan to handle the form posting using AJAX.

So I need away to edit the return when i post the email address to the server and i need a way of editing what the user sees when they return to the site to confirm there registration.

I hope this makes sense,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the name of extension that you are using? There are several add-ons that handle mailing lists, so please be specific.

Comment: The built in one http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/mailinglist/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to customize the system message look and feel.

You can edit the native **[User Message Template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/message_pages/index.html#user-message-template)** in EE

OR

Use the **[Custom System Message](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages)** addon which gives you a ton more control.